# How can I know how much time has been the smartphone on since the last turned off in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, smartphone

I need to know how much time the smartphone has been on but I don't find any library or native react native function to access it. Does there exist a way to see that?

Comment: You mean how much time has been _the smartphone on_ or _your app on foreground_?

Comment: Foreground, not in my app. I need just to know how much time has been passed since the last turn off of the mobile

Comment: You might have to write native(Java and Swift) code for this.

Comment: Why? Doesn't exists any library?

Comment: Because probably there is no such library yet.